# The check50 command returns an error for my print_winner function

Tags: c, for-loop, printf, cs50

The print_winner function must find the candidate who has the highest votes and print its name. In case there are more than 1 who have the same number of votes, the function must print their names.
here is the error

```
:) print_winner identifies Alice as winner of election
:) print_winner identifies Bob as winner of election
:( print_winner identifies Charlie as winner of election
    print_winner function did not print winner of election
:) print_winner prints multiple winners in case of tie
:) print_winner prints all names when all candidates are tied
```

mycode

```
void print_winner(void)
{
    int lenght = sizeof(candidates[0].votes);
    for (int i = 1; i < lenght - 1 ; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[0].votes <= candidates[i].votes)
        {
            candidates[0].votes = candidates[i].votes;
        }
        if (candidates[0].votes == candidates[i].votes)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", candidates[0].name);
    return;
}
```

Comment: What is `candidates`? What is `candidates[0]`? What is `candidates[0].votes`? Please create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: And for counting in general, you can't really display a result until you have gone through *all* elements to be counted. You can't declare a "winner" in the middle of a loop.

Comment: it's all working perfect but it breaks if there are 2 condidats a,b and 3 votes, b , b, invalide vote \\ it should print b but it print b a

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are "switching" the number of votes. The names remain the same. (And the final print **always** prints candidate[0].name, which is *always* the first candidate entered at the command line).

Give your solution some more thought. It needs to answer 2 questions. How much is the most number of votes? Which candidate(s) has that number of votes? It can be accomplished with two loops through the candidates. Good luck.